# Enabling Syntax in Vim Creates Lag

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-html, filetype-javascript

I was trying to learn javascript the other day and was using emacs as I have been trying to learn emacs as well. But after sometimes my left wrist started to hurt(as one's does) so I switched to neovim and noticed a significant amount of lag in html files with
    document.write();
statements for some reason. I turned off the syntax highlighting and the lag was gone. I am using joshdick/onedark.vim colorscheme. I thought about changing into some other colorscheme, but I would rather stay in this one as my all other resources use the same colorscheme.

Any idea how to cope with this?

Comment: Unless the colorscheme is defining its own syntax rules (blech), the lag is likely from a slow regex in a syntax file. Do you have javascript syntax files other than those from the standard distribution?

Comment: I have vim-polyglot. Disabling it removes the lag. Can you explain why it caused this scenario? I don't know about regex, I mean I know what it is but I don't know it's use in vim. So, should I just not use vim-polyglot? I don't use it exclusively, I just somewhere picked it up. @DavidBenKnoble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Vim-polyglot

vim-polyglot contains what it calls 'language packs', which are sets of syntax, ftplugin, and other files that 'enhance' the experience of working with a particular language. These files work as explained by the help reference, in particular at `:help rtp` and various topics like `syntax`, `ftplugin`, &c.

### Regexes/syntax

Regexes are common to syntax files as a way to define for Vim that, say, `var` is a keyword and `123` is a constant. If a regex is 'slow', it will slow down syntax highlighting.

By 'slow' I mean that vim's regex engine has a hard time handling it efficiently; this is always a known limitation of regexes, although for the most part vim handles them quite well.

### Fixes

- Suffer through slowness (but this is Vim, not emacs, so I'm going to guess you *don't* want that)
- Turn off syntax highlighting (apparently there is a trend of people doing this to focus better?)
- Remove your vim-polyglot (consider filing a bug related to your specific language `js`)

  - If they then fix the bug, you can reuse the plugin

---

<sub>Lacking the time and effort to fully explain syntax files/the runtime path, I'm going to point any curious readers to [here](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/42.html) (thank you Steve Losh). In fact, if you haven't already, the whole book there is a good read.</sub>

Comment: In your 2nd point under "Fixes", did you want to say "Turn **off** syntax highlighting" ?

Comment: Indeed. Will edit